# Javascript create dynamic object inside object and access its properties

Tags: javascript

I am getting the name of the user everytime the script is called and storing it in a variable called `name`

And I have a object which is initially `null` and I want it to be populated based on the name that I read.

I have this object

```
var usernames = {
    name1: {
        name: "ajey",
        room: 1,
        isStudent: true,
        isTeacher: false
    },
    name2: {
        name: "ajey-teacher",
        room: 1,
        isStudent: false,
        isTeacher: true
    },
    name3: {
        name: "batman",
        room: 2,
        isStudent: true,
        isTeacher: false
    }
};
```

Later I would print all the objects along with its key and value in the usernames object
like,

```
for(var i in usernames) {
 console.log(i.name1.name);
}
```

Here is the fiddle I am working on but I am having some issues.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/2Au8X/)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
for (var i in usernames) {
    console.log(usernames[i].name);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Au8X/1/)

Comment: Got it. And how do I create the name1, name2, name3 objects and so on dynamically ? based on the variable name

Answer (score 2):

The loop should be:

```
for (var i in usernames) {
    console.log(usernames[i].name);
}
```

When you use `for-in`, the variable is set to the property name. To use a dynamic property name, you have to use bracket syntax; dot syntax is only for literal properties.

You can also use bracket syntax to create properties dynamically:

```
usernames['name'+i] = {
    name: "batman",
    room: 2,
    isStudent: true,
    isTeacher: false
};
```

Comment: Got it. And how do I create the name1, name2, name3 objects and so on dynamically ? based on the variable name

Comment: Added explanation of that.

Comment: Although I wonder why you're using an object. Usually when you find yourself using names with consecutive numbers like this, you should actually be using an array.

Comment: Actually I am building a chat application in node and socket. So initially when the client connects to the chat, I am storing all the details like name, room no, role inside an object(which is his username) and this object is stored inside a global usernames object.
So with this later I can process in which room or role the user belongs to.
Is this a good approach ?

Comment: OK, that makes sense. These names were just examples, in real life they wouldn't have a pattern like this.